# Javascript audio channel activity

Tags: javascript, audio, webkit, mobile-safari

Is it possible to get some values regarding channel activity under Javascript? Im looking to draw the classical 4 power-bars that move in sync with the music.

Note: I am not looking to record or alter the soundfile being played in any way, just get some activity values that i can use to bounce CSS bars up and down in tune with the music.

Target is webkit (Safari + Chrome on android, both stationary and mobile if possible).

Comment: I believe the term is "vumeter"

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be looking for is the HTML5 Audio Data API. The good news is that it exists, and it looks fairly simple to implement, the bad news is that it has very, very little compatibility at the moment (looks like the latest versions of Firefox right now).

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API

You might be able to get away with using SoundManager2's peakData, but this relies on Flash, which isn't available on all Android devices.

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/

Comment: Yes it's it in the audio API ofcourse, but im looking for an example of how to catch the bytestream before it's send to the speakers. I havent coded audio stuff since C++, but i seem to remember that you get a byte per sample, which is signed - perfect for a vumeter